# Mui card & box sizing fix

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want my user page box to expand out to 100% but maxWidth set to 1000px but when i put it in phone mode in inspect, the box is too big for the screen meaning there is likely some minimum width built in the card or the box or maybe the inputs are limiting the width. Heres ny code:

```
    <Box
      sx={{
        height: "100%",
        p: 2,
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        flexDirection: "column",
      }}
    >
      <Card raised style={{ maxWidth: "1000px" }}>
        <CardContent>
          <Tabs value={tabValue} onChange={handleTabChange}>
            <Tab label="General" />
            <Tab label="Account" />
            <Tab label="Change Password" />
          </Tabs>
          <TabPanel value={tabValue} index={0}>
            <div className="flex column">
              <Typography variant="h5">General</Typography>
              <FormControl margin="normal">
                <TextField
                  label="Username"
                  variant="outlined"
                  value={username}
                  onChange={(e) => change(e, setUsername)}
                  error={errors === "username"}
                  helperText={
                    errors === "username" && "Enter a shorter username"
                  }
                />
              </FormControl>
              <FormControl margin="normal">
                <TextField
                  label="Email"
                  variant="outlined"
                  value={email}
                  disabled
                  onChange={(e) => change(e, setEmail)}
                />
              </FormControl>
              <FormControl margin="normal">
                <InputLabel id="time-format-label">Time Format</InputLabel>
                <Select
                  label="Time Format"
                  labelId="time-format-label"
                  id="time-format-select"
                  value={select}
                  onChange={handleSelectChange}
                >
                  <MenuItem value="12hrs">12hrs</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="24hrs">24hrs</MenuItem>
                </Select>
              </FormControl>{" "}
              <FormControl margin="normal">
                <InputLabel id="timezone-label">Timezone</InputLabel>
                <Select
                  label="Timezone"
                  labelId="timezone-label"
                  id="timezone-select"
                  value={timezone}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setTimezone(e.target.value);
                    setUpdated(true);
                  }}
                >
                  {sortedTimezones.map((tz) => {
                    const formattedTimezone = moment()
                      .tz(tz.timezone)
                      .format(HourFormat() === "h:mmaa" ? "h:mma" : "HH:mm");
                    const isCurrentTimezone =
                      isSameHour(
                        parse(formattedTimezone, HourFormat(), new Date()),
                        new Date()
                      ) &&
                      isSameMinute(
                        parse(formattedTimezone, HourFormat(), new Date()),
                        new Date()
                      );
                    return (
                      <MenuItem key={tz.timezone} value={tz.id}>
                        {formattedTimezone} - {tz.name}
                        <b
                          style={{
                            display: isCurrentTimezone ? "block" : "none",
                          }}
                        >
                          Your Time
                        </b>
                      </MenuItem>
                    );
                  })}
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                onClick={handleSubmit}
                disabled={!updated}
                sx={{ mt: 2 }}
              >
                Save
              </Button>
            </div>
          </TabPanel>
          <TabPanel value={tabValue} index={1}>
            <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
              Account
            </Typography>
            <FormControl margin="normal" fullWidth>
              <TextField
                label="Company Page"
                variant="outlined"
                value={link}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setErrors("");
                  setUpdated(true);
                  setLink(e.target.value);
                }}
                InputProps={{
                  endAdornment: (
                    <Link href={`/${link}`}>
                      <OpenInNew style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} />
                    </Link>
                  ),
                }}
                error={errors === "link"}
                helperText={errors === "link" && "Please use a different link"}
              />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl margin="normal" fullWidth>
              <TextField
                label="Description"
                variant="outlined"
                rows={3}
                multiline
                value={desc}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setErrors("");
                  setUpdated(true);
                  setDesc(e.target.value);
                }}
                error={errors === "desc"}
                helperText={
                  errors === "desc" && "Please provide a proper description"
                }
              />
            </FormControl>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              onClick={handleSubmit}
              disabled={!updated}
            >
              Save
            </Button>
          </TabPanel>
          <TabPanel value={tabValue} index={2}>
            <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
              Change Password
            </Typography>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              disabled={requested}
              color="primary"
              onClick={handleRequestResetToken}
              sx={{ mt: 2 }}
            >
              Request Password Reset Token
            </Button>
            <FormControl margin="normal" fullWidth>
              <TextField
                label="Reset Token"
                variant="outlined"
                value={resetToken}
                onChange={(e) => setResetToken(e.target.value)}
              />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl margin="normal" fullWidth>
              <TextField
                label="New Password"
                variant="outlined"
                type="password"
                value={newPassword}
                onChange={(e) => setNewPassword(e.target.value)}
              />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl margin="normal" fullWidth>
              <TextField
                label="Confirm New Password"
                variant="outlined"
                type="password"
                value={confirmNewPassword}
                onChange={(e) => setConfirmNewPassword(e.target.value)}
              />
            </FormControl>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              onClick={handleResetPassword}
              sx={{ mt: 2 }}
            >
              Reset Password
            </Button>
          </TabPanel>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
      <Snackbar open={updating} autoHideDuration={3000}>
        <Alert severity="success">Changes Saved!</Alert>
      </Snackbar>
      <Snackbar open={error} autoHideDuration={3000}>
        <Alert severity="error">Token Expired!</Alert>
      </Snackbar>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="secondary"
        onClick={props.logout}
        sx={{ mt: 2 }}
      >
        Logout
      </Button>
    </Box>
```

I've treid removing form controls and fullWidth options but nothing works.